# Как выводит img через код на экран?

Tags: php, img

`<?php echo <img src='$myrow['img'];/> ?>`

Исправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Aki Sulaymonov, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

    [телепат]Разберитесь с кавычками, у вас их явно не хватает[/телепат]

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo '<img src="' . $myrow['img'] . '">'; ?>
```

Comment: @Aki Sulaymonov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).